# Return SQL as array

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple SQL statement written in SQLDeveloper and I wish to display each returned result as an array so I can list them individually (iterate through them) in my front-end application (in this case its a chatbot). Right now all the returned results are shown when I run the statement.

Anyone has any easy solution to this?

```
SELECT STRING job_class_title, entry_salary_beg, entry_salary_end, job_duties 
From SQLLEGENDS 
Where Entry_salary_beg >= 80000 and entry_salary_end <= 120000
  And DRIVERS_LICENSE_REQ = 'P' and JOB_DUTIES like '%Senior%';
```

Comment: Surely this is a problem with the front-end. The SQL is returning a results set and you can iterate over that row-by-row in your chatbot rather than trying to aggregate all the rows into arrays (that you will still need to iterate over).

Comment: What is your chatbot written in? What are you using to retrieve the data? How are you displaying it?

Comment: In oracle 12c and higher you can use "SELECT json_arrayagg(job_class_title), json_arrayagg(entry_salary_beg), json_arrayagg(entry_salary_end), json_arrayagg(job_duties) From SQLLEGENDS" to get JSON arrays from each column individually and then convert it to some array of your frontend language. It's easy, language-independent and no need to iterate because it will aggregate all results in one row.

Comment: Hi, 

The chatbot displays the whole returned result as one long string. 

Normally for example, if I have an excel it displays each row as an object and I can iterate through. The way its set up now is that I have a data warehouse with some dummy data. I have an integration cloud service on-top of that. From the integration service I have created a REST API which I can call from the chatbots custom component (Node.js built) to retrieve the results from the SQL statement which is on my API. 

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to display each returned result as an array

Returning each column as an separate array:

```
SELECT CAST( COLLECT( string           ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST ) AS job_class_title,
       CAST( COLLECT( entry_salary_beg ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST   ) AS entry_salary_beg,
       CAST( COLLECT( entry_salary_end ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST   ) AS entry_salary_end,
       CAST( COLLECT( job_duties       ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST ) AS job_duties
FROM   SQLLEGENDS 
WHERE  Entry_salary_beg    >= 80000
AND    entry_salary_end    <= 120000
AND    DRIVERS_LICENSE_REQ = 'P'
AND    JOB_DUTIES like '%Senior%';
```

Returning each row as an array:

```
SELECT SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
         string,
         TO_CHAR( entry_salary_beg ),
         TO_CHAR( entry_salary_end ),
         job_duties
       ) AS array
FROM   SQLLEGENDS 
WHERE  Entry_salary_beg    >= 80000
AND    entry_salary_end    <= 120000
AND    DRIVERS_LICENSE_REQ = 'P'
AND    JOB_DUTIES like '%Senior%';
```

*However, I really don't think you want to do this. Returning a results set from your existing query should be the way to achieve what you wish and then you just need to iterate over the results set row-by-row rather than over-complicating things by using arrays.*

*You need to change the behaviour of the chatbot not the behaviour of the SQL query.*